# Implementing a custom getter in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

I am working with Yii and I have the following situation:

I have a MySQL table:

```
charges {
    id INT AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(256),
    value DOUBLE
}
```

Then I have the model from this table. And finally I have the views for create, list, admin,  update and view.

In the **admin** and **view** views I want to display the `value` field formated with two decimal numbers. One option to do this could be in the **view** and **admin** files format the number. Is there a way to create a method in the model and then not having to do anything in the views but the method itself will solve formating the number?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [afterFind() method of CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) in your model and format the `value` field in it.

Alternatively you could also declare a virtual attribute of the model, and set it in the afterFind() method, and use this virtual attribute in the views.

Example(with virtual attribute):

```
Class ChargesModel extends CActiveRecord{
    public $valueModified;

    /*
     * other code
     */

    protected function afterFind(){
        parent::afterFind();
        // in the following line i'm just making $valueModified and $value equal, but obviously you would have to insert the 2 decimals
        $this->valueModified=$this->value;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the virtual attribute like this : `$modelObject->valueModified`

I would recommend you to use the virtual attribute, because you then have both the unmodified `$value` and modified `$modifiedValue`, once the formatting is done, we can use either as required, and not have to reformat back to original when we need the original.